# Work done by forces and their pathways?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Currently studying the mathematics of work. Quick question if the application of force is constant does that automatically imply that the pathway will be linear, and analogously if the force applied is varying does that also automatically imply that the pathway will be nonlinear?

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To both questions, I think the answer is no. I will provide a counterexample for each case.

Question 1:

If you have a 1kg object at the origin with initial velocity $v=(0,5)$ and you apply a constant resultant force $F=(3,0)$, then the motion of the mass looks like this:
[image]

Question 2:

Consider the same situation except now you apply a force of $F=(0,2t)$, the motion of the mass looks like this:

[image]

Hopefully, it'll make sense intuitively why these will create curved and straight paths, but if not, I can show how to arrive at these Cartesian equations of motion mathematically.

Comment: Yeah it makes perfects sense thanks a lot. was just a little baffled as to why my textbook only provided cases in which constant force was applied to a straight pathway or in one dimension and not in a varying path, and the case where varying force was applied to a nonlinear pathway and not a straight path.

Comment: The reason is because your textbook is trying to provide situations with only simple math at the expense of not providing you the full picture.